# ActionController::UrlGenerationError when trying to test namespaced controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write a controller specs for one of my controller action defined under `Front` namespace (and living in `Front` engine mounted in root rails app). I've been following this thing to acheive that: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/engine-routes-for-controllers

Here is my code:

```
# config/routes/rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Front::Engine => '/', as: 'front'
end
```

---

```
# modules/front/config/routes.rb
Front::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :items
end
```

---

```
# modules/front/app/controllers/front/items_controller.rb
class Front::ItemsController < Front::ApplicationController
  def index
    # ...
  end
end
```

---

```
# spec/controllers/front/items_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Front::ItemsController, type: :controller do
  routes { Front::Engine.routes }

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assings @items" do
      item = FactoryGirl.create(:item)
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:items)).to eq([item])
    end
  end
end
```

---

Running above spec gives me:

```
Front::ItemsController
  GET index
    assings @items (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Front::ItemsController GET index assings @items
     Failure/Error: get :index

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"front/items"}
```

It all works fine outside of specs, i can totally access that endpoint. Any ideas what's wrong in here? Thanks in advance.

- ruby 2.3.1
- rspec 3.4.4
- rails 4.2.1

Comment: I would think you should either (a) remove the `routes` declaration or (b) put the file in `spec/controllers/items_controller_spec.rb`.  As-is, you are trying to test against the engine within a namespace you made up, which doesn't seem like a natural fit. Just a thought.

Comment: your code actually looks right to me, not sure what's going wrong, sorry! this stuff unfortunately gets messy. Try taking out the `routes` line in your spec and see if that magically works?

Comment: unfortunately, none of those two solutions above worked guys :(

Comment: Adding the 'route {}' sentence did fixed the problem for me.

I have something like this now:

`describe MyEngine::V1::MyController do
  routes { MyEngine::Engine.routes }
end
`

And my specs lives in my_engine/spec/controllers/v1/my_controller_spec.rb